# How did Shaktimaan lose his abilities?

Tags: shaktimaan

In the East Indian Super hero TV series *Shaktimaan,* the titular hero was a normal human who had practiced high level of yoga to develop psychic powers. These included flight, transmutation, and various physical and mental enhancements. I vaguely recall one episode where he lost his powers for some reason, (was years ago, and the series was subtitled, so I may have missed some stuff).

Can anyone explain how and/or in what episode this power loss occured?

Comment: @Valorum You coming down with that same Snark Flu Adamant been sick with, aren't you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for a physical artifact, then the [Papmani](http://webot.org/info/en/?search=Shaktimaan#Powers) possessed by Tamraj Kilvish is able to negate his powers.

> Although [Shaktimaan] possesses godlike powers, his only weakness is a crystal (Papmani) possessed by Tamraj Kilvish which can be used to defeat and even kill him. This makes him powerless because it is filled with the evil of the world and is the source of the black powers. But he regains his strength after the crystal is taken away from him. He can be killed if the crystal is placed in front of him and he is treated violently to the verge of death.

One example might be [this video](https://vimeo.com/359080596), although I'm not certain what episode it came from, and looks to have been re-edited. [Episode 325](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SW-g77Upeec) has Tamraj chaining said gem to Shaktimaan to keep him from being able to use his powers to escape and also has an incident where he uses a plate on his chest to disable Shaktimaan (although, if I'm not mistaken, his reporter guise is in the crowd while he's being disabled, so maybe this is another case of a clone).

Comment: Okay, that sounds more like it. What episode was this?

Comment: @Russhiro: Every example I've found so far has been a temporary removal of powers, something akin to how Lex Luthor will have Superman powerless for a while in the presence of Kryptonite. But you are looking for a longer removal, say for an entire episode?

Comment: No no, the kryptonite example is find. I just finished watching the 4 episode arc where his powers were "stripped" for misuse. And that wasn't "his powers in a seperate form", apparently, but some kind of clone. Thing is, though, if his kundalin abilities stem from proper use.... then _why_ didn't his patron gurus strip _the clone_ of _his_ abilities when he came into being? Hell, _how_ could an evil clone **exist** in the first place?!
But yeah, any episodes with the kryptonite analog crystal would probably be the ones I was thinking about.

Comment: @fuzzyboots- Is there an episode guide which can show in which other episodes the Papmani crystal was used?

Comment: @Russhiro: not that I know of. I'll admit, though, that my familiarity with the series is pretty much limited to me answering questions on this site. :)

Answer (score 2):

In the paper, ["Shaktimaan : The Cultural Emergence of an Indian Super Hero"](http://www.iosrjournals.org/iosr-jhss/papers/Vol.%2021%20Issue2/Version-5/G021253854.pdf), they note that he loses his powers by having used them improperly.

> Later, he left the college in order to work for a news channel KR
> TV with Geeta. . She died in a crash at space planned by Dr.Jaikal. Shaktimaan too loved her and brought her
> back to life again using his power which resulted in losing his powers temporally due to his action which are
> against the law of nature. Shaktimaan regained his power taking the vow not ever to misuse it again.

This happens in Episode 101.

Comment: Well this makes sense, considering the"harmony" basis of his powers. It's not the one I recall, though. There was some kind of good or curse or element, some physical _thing_ I think, that negated his abilities at one point. And how did Dr. Jaikal gain _his_ abilities, while we're on it?

Comment: @Russhiro My impression is that he's just that good at the sciences.

Comment: And apparently richer than _Elonk Musk,_ as well. Just watched the episode, and seems dude had a whole **Star Destroyer battle cruiser** from the Galactic empire made! With the royal purple cape _and_ suit, he had that "snappy dresser" power, too!

Comment: @Russhiro This is the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Another situation where Shaktimaan lost his powers was against [Kakodar](http://webot.org/info/en/?search=Shaktimaan#Other_enemies), although I haven't pinpointed which episode.

> [Kakodar] is cunning enough to be able to use mental manipulation to trick Shaktimaan on occasion. This put the hero into a dilemma, and self-doubt drained him of his powers temporarily.

Comment: I was speaking of the Papmani crystal, friend. But thanks.